# BDE Issue with Win 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, informix, windows-7-x64, bde

I have made an application in Delphi with informix as a database. I am using BDE to connect with the database. It works fine on Win xp however this application doesn't run on Win7. As application is launched it stops. Can you plesae help. I tried this link but doesn't work:

http://www.willneumann.net/2008/09/configuring-bde-for-windows7/

Comment: Which BDE version is installed on that system? There is a special version to work with x64 OS http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/27573

Comment: Can you please let me know how to track the version?

Comment: You may try to track your app initialization sequence, what registry and files it reads,  on both computers using SysInternals Process Monitor. Then compare where non-working program failed

Comment: Try Devart-Unidac,we had BDE in our project and we have migrated for supporting Win7

Comment: Is there any other workarround?
I tried as suggested by @Sir Rufo But doesn't work

Comment: Is there any workarround or configurable fix for this @Aron

Comment: I have tested the BDE Info utility and it says the bde is working properly. What else can be the issue with the application not running properly.

Answer (score 1):

The BDE is a very old product. It remains in delphi to be downwards compatible to old source.
On a new project I would never use the BDE.
On The [BDE Alternatives Guide](http://delphibag.com/) you find alternatives for the BDE.
May [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) or SqlDirect is a good solution to connect to Informix.

Comment: @Arioch Unfortunetly BDE will not support on Win7 platform and Borland itself depcreted BDE..So trail and error method not gonna work,i feel only solution is to migrate from BDE.

Comment: @SSE ditching BDE is a very good advice, very good. But still not an answer. PS: AFAIr BDE is not supported on ANY Windows - it is EOLed, though people manage to run it even in Win8 x64

Answer (score 0):

I've used mOdbc package created by Konstantin Savelyev in the past to connect to Informix databases. It can be downloaded from here:
https://sites.google.com/site/robsosno/Home/downloads .

mOdbc is a set of components for Delphi 7 to work with Odbc with sources.
I don't know if it works with Windows 7. I think that it should.

Currently I'm not using this - in my company we've migrated from Delphi to C#.